# appending arrays into session variable php

Tags: php

Im trying to add additional arrays into my session variable such as...

```
$_SESSION[cart] .= array($_POST[name],$_POST[price],$_POST[quantity]);
```

All i get when i do this 3 times and `var_dump` is `string(15) "ArrayArrayArray"`

Answer (score 3):

Youre using .= "." is for string concat so youre arrays are getting converted to strings you should use one of the following:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array($_POST[name],$_POST[price],$_POST[quantity]);

$_SESSION['cart'] += array($_POST[name],$_POST[price],$_POST[quantity]);

array_push(array($_POST[name],$_POST[price],$_POST[quantity]), (array) $_SESSION['cart'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r` and see the content of the array.

i.e., `print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: `Var_dump` often gives more information then `print_r`. I really don't see how or why this would be any help.